# Consuming an private eventsource API, passing headers

Tags: api, http, authentication, rust, server-sent-events

A good day for everyone.

I'm in a need of consuming an eventsource API,  but it's a private one, where I need to pass some auth headers, specifically the Authorization one, and some more.

I had a look into these "two" crates, but neither of them explains how to pass some headers, has someone passed by something related, or knows how to set it up in these crates?

Crates:

- [eventsource](https://docs.rs/eventsource/latest/eventsource/)
- [reqwest_eventsource](https://docs.rs/reqwest-eventsource/latest/reqwest_eventsource/)

Comment: _"I had a look into these 'two' crates"_ -- Which two crates?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in eventsource with Client::new_with_client():

```
use eventsource::reqwest::Client as EventSourceClient;
use reqwest::{blocking::Client as ReqwestClient, header::HeaderMap};

let mut headers = HeaderMap::new();
headers.insert("Authorization", "Basic Zm9vOmJhcg==".parse()?);
headers.insert("X-Foo", "bar".parse()?);
let client = ReqwestClient::builder().default_headers(headers).build()?;
let client = EventSourceClient::new_with_client("https://example.com/".parse()?, client);
```